# Javascript: How to create a select list option from a textbox?

Tags: javascript, html, textbox

How would I have my select list populate with a new option from user input?

Here's my JS so far for it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function show_prompt() {
    var name = prompt('Please enter new origin');
    if (name != null && name != "") {
      var select = document.getElementById("OriginSelect");
      select.options[select.options.length] = new Option('Text 1', 'Value1');
    }
}
```

Here is the HTML\Coldfusion down below in the body:

```
<p class="_30NP" align="right">
                                <label>Origin&nbsp;</label>
                            </p>

                            <p class="_20NP">
                              <cfselect  name="OriginSelect" id="OriginSelect" query="Origin" display="description" value="code"  required="yes">
                              <option id="new" value="new" onClick="show_prompt()">New Origin</option>
                              </cfselect>
                            </p>

                            <a href="#" onClick="show_prompt()">New Origin</a>
```

So basically, the list gets populated from the database but when there is not an appropriate Origin available, the user can click the href and a prompt box appears with a text field (this works just fine). The user may then input whatever he likes and then the JS script adds a new  element to the  tag.

However it does not do anything after the user hits "ok" upon entering in the text and doing OK. The javascript debugger in Chrome does not show anything useful either, no errors are flagged or anything.

Is the fact that it is a cfselect a problem? I added an option inside of it myself manually (id="new") and it displays just fine.

Edit: Ok it's not the cfselect's fault. I made it into a regular select box and it still wouldn't work..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `appendChild` function

```
function show_prompt() {
    var name = prompt('Please enter new origin');
    if (name != null && name != "") {
      var select = document.getElementById("OriginSelect");
      var option = new Option(name);
      select.appendChild(option);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid this results in the same as with the code I provided.. It doesn't do anything =(

Comment: It absolutely works there lol, but on my server it doesn't work.. Something is interfering with it..

This is pretty frustrating. I'm getting no feedback from the JS console or anything as to what could be screwing it up.

Comment: Ok, it does work on my server. It's just that, for some reason, although the <option> tag is on the page according to the javascript console\chrome tools, it isn't rendering for me to see. It's hidden..